# Pandas using stack or melt(using columns as rows) with multiple rows as column header

Tags: python, excel, pandas, multi-index, read-data

I need to use the melt function(pandas) in order to turn my data table into a 1-dimensional format, but I have columns with two rows, and based on my research I had to use multi indexing for defining those rows as columns.

for instance:

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(
        df.iloc[:2].apply(list, 1))
df = df.iloc[2:].reset_index(drop=True)
```

After this when I apply melt function:

```
        df = df.melt(id_vars=df.columns[[0,1]],
                 var_name='columns', value_name='Value')
```

I get this error: ValueError("Can only tuple-index with a MultiIndex")
ValueError: Can only tuple-index with a MultiIndex

Data format that I have:

```
    A B C
    D E F 
X Y 1 2 3
Z T 4 5 6
```

Data format that I need to reach:

```
X Y A D 1
X Y B E 2
X Y C F 3
Z T A D 4
Z T B E 5
Z T C F 6
```

I am not very experienced in python, so if you can help me I would be so happy. Thanks in advance

Comment: kindly share sample data with expected output. Not pics.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) for set new columns names with reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), last convert `MultiIndex Series` to `DataFrame` by [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html):

```
df1 = df.rename_axis(['a','b'], axis=1).stack(level=[0,1]).reset_index(name='c')
```

In [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) is possible use only one level, not both:

```
df2 = df.melt(col_level=0, ignore_index=False)
df3 = df.melt(col_level=1, ignore_index=False)
#failed
df4 = df.melt(col_level=[0,1], ignore_index=False)
```